# Use latest Mono 5.4 with MonoDevelop Flatpak installation

Tags: mono, monodevelop, flatpak

I've installed MonoDevelop using the [official Flatpak package for Linux](http://www.monodevelop.com/download/#lin). However, version of Mono bundled in that package is 5.2.

Is there a way to use the latest version of Mono (5.4), which I have already installed on the system?